# Find out when unit tests are ran in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to find out how often and how much time I spend *running*, not writing, unit tests. I'm using Test Explorer and VSTest from within Visual Studio 2015.

Is this information logged anywhere?

Comment: `/TestResults` in your solution directory contains the result of the tests, in subdirectories for each run -- but those are emptied by MsTest.exe  when the tests succeed. You can prevent this deletion of the results through the `DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete` property setting. You'll need to add a `.runsettingsfile` to accomplish that. See here for more properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx

Comment: There would be no info on how often, but for each test case its execution time can be seen directly, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx

Comment: Thank you, the subdirectories are enough to see when the tests are being run.